# Remove duplicated labels from ggplot2 while using interaction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to remove/reduce/merge labels in my legend. I need to use "interaction" as only this solutions orders my boxplots into desired order (RBY, RBY, RBY). Right now i got:

[image]

What i would like to achieve:

[image]

My code:

```
  data("iris")

  iris$Col <- as.factor(rep(c("blue","red", "yellow")))

  df <- melt(iris,id.vars=c("Species","Col"), measure.vars=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))

  ggplot(df,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=interaction(Species, Col))) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", position=pd, width=0.3)+
    geom_boxplot(width=0.4, position=pd)+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)+
    theme(text=element_text(family="Times"))+
    grids(axis="x", linetype = "dotted")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red", "blue", "yellow"), length(unique(df$variable))*2),labels=c("R", "B", "Y"))
```

Anything I found about reducing labels was only using combination of two elements chosen from color/fill/shape. Unfortunately specifying my plot by those doesn't give shuffled order (RBY, RBY, RBY) but rather grouped (RRR, BBB, YYY). Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using the fill as a grouping variable, which is fine is straightforward cases, but because you have it is not the only relevant factor you might want to explicitly define groups.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Col, group = interaction(Species, Col, variable))) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", position= position_dodge2(), width=0.3)+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.3, position=position_dodge2())+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "yellow"),
                    labels = c("R", "B", "Y"))
```

Comment: That's really smooth and solves the issue, thank you. The only thing is that I had to change fill=Col into fill=Species to get the desired output.